# Send POST request with parameters in body via Play WS API

Tags: scala, web-services, playframework, playframework-2.0

Currently, I am sending get requests via the Play WS API as follows:

```
wsClient
    .url(myUrl)
    .withQueryString(getParams(): _*)
    .get()
```

Now I want to change this call to use HTTP Post. When calling the following:

```
    wsClient
        .url(myUrl)
        .withMethod("POST")
        .withBody(getParams(): _*)
        .get()
```

I receive the following error:

> Cannot write an instance of Seq[(String, String)] to HTTP response. Try to define a Writeable[Seq[(String, String)]]

I guess it's because the method `getParams` returns `Seq[(String, String)]`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You should end your call with `.post()`... See the [docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaWS#Request-with-additional-headers).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I replaced `get()` with `post(getParams(): _*)` and removed `.withBody(getParams(): _*)` but I still get the same error.

Comment: Also `.withBody(getParams(): _*)` is wrong.. What are you sending as **body**, some JSON, XML? Query string is just URL parameters like `?id=5&name=whatever`.

Comment: The payload for the POST request should be something like `key123=val123&key456=val456`. My method `getParams` returns a `Seq[(String, String)]`, for example `List("key123" -> "val123", "key456" -> "val456")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using http post key value pairs are sent using content type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Here is the code for posting

```
 client.url(myUrl)
    .withHeaders("Content-type" -> "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    .post(getParams.map { case (k, v) => s"$k=$v"}.mkString("&"))
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much! Have a nice day.